# Error when using libraries in C

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I'm trying to play an mp3 file in terminal using C and I followed [this](http://hzqtc.github.io/2012/05/play-mp3-with-libmpg123-and-libao.html) link to do so.
I've installed the two libraries `libmpg123` and `libao`. Also, I've compiled the play.c program using the command:

```
gcc -O2 -o play play.c -lmpg123 -lao
```

But I get the following error when I run it:

```
./play: error while loading shared libraries: libao.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Can you figure it out why it happened.

Comment: what kind of distribution do you use?

Comment: i have leaved Ubuntu 5 yeara before, but what was the name of the package you have installed? libao-dev?

Comment: What is your LD_LIBRARY_PATH ?

Comment: @Jim that command gives the following error
`./play:
 linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff517fe000)
 libmpg123.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpg123.so.0 (0x00007f69702fc000)
 libao.so.4 => not found
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f696ff35000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f696fc2f000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f697056d000)`

Comment: See?  It can't find the libao.so.4.  You need to find out where it was installed and add the path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The executable can be linked, but at run-time, it cannot find the shared libraries.  Add the libraries to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH so the program can find them at run time.

Comment: I've never added the library path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I only used `configure`, `make` and `make install`. But, how can I find the location of the installed library?

Comment: Look for it.  Grep it.  It's probably in usr/shared/libs or some such place.

Comment: I cannot find it. It is not installed in `/usr/lib/` folder and `/usr/shared/libs` does not exist.

Comment: but the first library is installed in `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: go to / .   find . | grep libao

Comment: If it was really installed, it has to be there somewhere.  Perhaps re-install it and not where it was placed?

Comment: I found it - it is installed in `/usr/local/lib`. I added it to LD_LIBRARY_PATH and I recompiled it. But, it doesn't play the song.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51055/discussion-between-gowtham-and-jim)